# Android access to location makes the login screen Zoom in effect

Tags: codenameone

My applciation needs the location access from the device. During the login application requests the permission of the device. On the pop-up it display message asking the user to accept or deny permission. During this time login page will zoom in automatically in the background. Please advise how to fix this issue. Thanks

[image]

Comment: You can tune the prompt to location by using the API sooner/later. The screenshot doesn't explain or demonstrate the issue.